# Run TeX-command on current buffer

Tags: auctex

I have bound `TeX-command` to a key `f7` to compile my document with `latexmk`. When I press it, and it needs to be compiled, it compiles it without asking. If not, views it, without asking (that's because of the -1 option):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'my-run-latex)

(defun my-run-latex ()
  (interactive)
  (if (equal current-buffer-hash
         (setq current-buffer-hash (secure-hash 'md5 (current-buffer))))
      (TeX-view)
    (setq TeX-save-query nil)
    (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file))
    (TeX-command "Latexmk" 'TeX-master-file -1)))
```

Now this applies to the tex master file. How can I make it apply to the file in the current buffer?

Note that I also want to have this command bound to another key for compiling the master file. So it wouldn't be a solution to set the current buffer as master file.

I tried to replace `(TeX-command "Latexmk" 'TeX-master-file -1)` by `(TeX-command-buffer "Latexmk")` which works but doesn't compile without asking. Then I tried to replace it with `(TeX-command "Latexmk" 'TeX-master-file -1)` with returns an error message "Wrong number of arguments buffer-file-name, 2".

Comment: Do you now that you can compile the document with `C-c C-a` (bound to `TeX-command-run-all`) that is akin to `latexmk`?

Comment: @giordano `C-c C-a` is bound to nothing and `Tex-command-run-all` doesn't exist in my emacs. Do you mean `C-c C-b` for the current buffer and `C-c C-c` for the master file?

Comment: No, I meant exactly `C-c C-a`.  You have an outdated version of AUCTeX, upgrade to version 11.89 and you'll enjoy this new feature.

Comment: If you want to override the default behavior you set a local var in the buffer. Then undo that to revert to default behavior. Make your function switch back and forth as there is not command that will do both automatically. See my answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make it apply to the file in the current buffer?

In two ways. Either insert these lines at the bottom of the current file:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-master: "thisFileName"
%%% End:
```

Or set the tex-master in your `my-run-latex` function by adding this line:

```
(setq-default TeX-master "thisFileName")
```

Where "thisFileName" is the current buffer's file name. When you want to revert back to "master", run `C-c _` as described in the [AucTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html).

Comment: That doesn't work, because then I couldn't compile the "real" master file anymore.

Comment: I made the answer clear now: you can switch back and forth.